# How to determine space and time complexity of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have an algorithm, I am not sure about time and space complexity. ,

```
for (i = 1 to n ) 
do
begin
R(xi) = random(o, xi, r)
i++
end
```

What is the time and space complexity in above algorithm and why?

Thanks

Comment: This is not C++. Don't just add random language tags.

Comment: You need to solve it like you solve any mathematical problem. There is no universal recipe. It is hard to answer your specific question because of non-standard notation you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Space and time complexity is in proportional to the size of input. Suppose there is an input array of size `n` and you are processing each element once, then time complexity is `O(n)`. If you use any data structure to store and process intermediate results, say another array of size `n`, then space complexity will be `O(n)`. There are many notations for complexity and different complexities such as `log n, n, n^2, n^3, n!`.

For your code time complexity is `O(n)` and space complexity depends on whether you have defined(`O(n)`) `R` or it is passed(`O(1)`) as parameter.

Refer here for more [Analysis of algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)